# ionic build stuck on lint finish

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

```
D:\myproj>ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts.cmd build --target cordova --platform android
[16:10:48]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.4 
[16:10:49]  build dev started ...
[16:10:49]  clean started ...
[16:10:49]  clean finished in 13 ms
[16:10:49]  copy started ...
[16:10:49]  deeplinks started ...
[16:10:49]  deeplinks finished in 277 ms
[16:10:49]  transpile started ...
[16:11:28]  transpile finished in 38.88 s
[16:11:28]  preprocess started ...
[16:11:28]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[16:11:28]  webpack started ...
[16:11:31]  copy finished in 41.80 s
[16:11:40]  webpack finished in 11.59 s
[16:11:40]  sass started ...
[16:11:49]  sass finished in 9.52 s
[16:11:49]  postprocess started ...
[16:11:49]  postprocess finished in 29 ms
[16:11:49]  lint started ...
[16:11:49]  build dev finished in 60.80 s
[16:12:21]  lint finished in 31.45 s
```

this was a template based on ionic 3 and angular 5, I have installed the latest version of the ionic and angular and run command

```
npm install
```

- node version: 12.14.0
- npm version: 6.13.4